# dependency property to chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property and i want to present in on a chart.

```
namespace ViewModels
{
  public partial class MyVM: DependencyObject
  {
    public Double TotalPowerSoFar
        {
            get { return (Double)GetValue(TotalPowerSoFarProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TotalPowerSoFarProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GroupReadingsBy.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TotalPowerSoFarProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TotalPowerSoFar", typeof(Double), typeof(EstimateVM), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));


    TotalPowerSoFar=5.0;
   }
}
```

I thought i'd do something like that:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Workspace"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
             xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
<DVC:Chart Name="mcChart"   Foreground="DarkBlue" Title="Area Chart" LegendTitle="Month Rating" >
                    <DVC:Chart.Series>
                        <DVC:ColumnSeries DependentValueBinding ="{Binding EstimatedTotalPower}"/>
                    </DVC:Chart.Series>
                </DVC:Chart>
</Grid>
```

But from what i understand the binding is wrong.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, dependency properties make any sense only for `DependencyObject` descendants, and your view model isn't a `DependencyObject`.

The second, if you want to extend functionality of the existing dependency object (`Chart` in your case), you should use [**attached**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) properties - they could be *attached* to DO and data bound to your view model.

Comment: Dennis,i need to use dependency properties for my project,so lets take it for granted.I edited so that MyVM is a DependencyObject.Can you help me on how to bind it to the Chart?

Comment: @yiannis, It seems to me, you're misunderstanding DP concepts. Please, provide am XAML sample **with** `TotalPowerSoFar` dependency property, which will be desired for you.